# Mudar Ordem ao Clicar na Tecla Tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando bootstrap em um projeto em c#, e quando clico na tecla tab para ir mudando os campos a direção está da direita para a esquerda, e queria que fosse ao contrário, onde é que mudo?
Ex: quando ele chega nos botôes salvar e cancelar ele vai primeiro no cancelar e depois no salvar. Como exemplo na foto abaixo.[image: Nagegação com a tecla TAB]

Comment: O projeto é ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Correto. asp.net mvc

Comment: Você está usando os helpers para gerar esses campos, certo?

Comment: Obrigada @jbueno ! Funcionou ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode passar a ordem dos campos nos `Html Helpers`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prop, new { tabindex = 1 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o atributo `tabindex="2"` no HTML. [Exemplo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_tabindex)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" tabindex="2">W3Schools</a><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" tabindex="1">Google</a><br>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/" tabindex="3">Microsoft</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> Try navigating the links by using the "Tab" button on you keyboard.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigada @Ricardo e @jbueno! Funcionou ;)